# Copy/paste: how to remove line breaks?

Tags: macos, pdf

When I copy text from a pdf, I almost systematically add line breaks when I paste it into a Word, Notion, etc. text file. 
I've tried opening the pdf with Adobe, the Chrome viewer, but nothing changes.
It costs me a lot of time.
There is a capture of the problem :

[image: img]

Do you have any idea how to get around this problem?
I'm on macos.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You cannot copy text directly from a pdf file without getting the line breaks, but you can convert the pdf file to Word and copy text from there. Use the (paid) version of Acrobat, or the (free) online converter https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/online/pdf-to-word.html